# Bulk Rename Files in a Folder - PHP

Tags: php

I have 1000 images in a Folder, which has SKU# word in all the images. For examples

```
WV1716BNSKU#.zoom.1.jpg
WV1716BLSKU#.zoom.3.jpg
```

what i need to do is read all the filenames and rename it to the following

```
WV1716BN.zoom.1.jpg
WV1716BL.zoom.3.jpg
```

So remove SKU# from filename, is it possible in PHP to do bulk renaming ?

Comment: You mean something like a loop that renames all the files?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Yeah, just open the directory and create a loop to access all images and rename them, like:

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('./path/to/files')) {
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
      if($fileName != '.' && $fileName != '..') {
         $newName = str_replace("SKU#","",$fileName);
         rename('./path/to/files/'.$fileName, './path/to/files'.$newName);
      }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 11):

piece of cake:

```
foreach (array_filter(glob("$dir/WV1716B*.jpg") ,"is_file") as $f)
  rename ($f, str_replace("SKU#", "", $f));
```

(or `$dir/*.jpg` if number doesn't matter)

Comment: =1 for simpler solution. edited: `array_filte`r take first parameter as array.

Comment: glob is usually a few times slower than directory iteration - so if you have a lot of files - that's a thing to consider: https://www.phparch.com/2010/04/putting-glob-to-the-test/

Answer (score 3):

The steps to completing this is pretty simple:

- iterate over each file using `fopen`, `readdir`
- for each file parse the file name into segments
- copy the old file into a new directly called old (sanity reasons)
- rename the root file top the new name.

A small example:

```
if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/images'))
{
    /* Create a new directory for sanity reasons*/
    if(is_directory('/path/to/images/backup'))
    {
         mkdir('/path/to/images/backup');
    }

    /*Iterate the files*/
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
    {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
          {
               if(!strstr($file,"#SKU"))
               {
                   continue; //Skip as it does not contain #SKU
               }

               copy("/path/to/images/" . $file,"/path/to/images/backup/" . $file);

               /*Remove the #SKU*/
               $newf = str_replace("#SKU","",$file);

               /*Rename the old file accordingly*/
               rename("/path/to/images/" . $file,"/path/to/images/" . $newf);
          }
    }

    /*Close the handle*/
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: This snippet works good but it also renamed the file's extensions. can u resolve it??

Answer (score 2):

Well, using iterators:

```
class SKUFilterIterator extends FilterIterator {
    public function accept() {
        if (!parent::current()->isFile()) return false;
        $name = parent::current()->getFilename();
        return strpos($name, 'SKU#') !== false;
    }
}
$it = new SkuFilterIterator(
    new DirectoryIterator('path/to/files')
);

foreach ($it as $file) {
    $newName = str_replace('SKU#', '', $file->getPathname());
    rename($file->getPathname(), $newName);
}
```

The FilterIterator basically filters out all non-files, and files without the `SKU#` in them.  Then all you do is iterate, declare a new name, and rename the file...

Or in 5.3+ using the **new** [GlobIterator](http://us.php.net/manual/en/class.globiterator.php):

```
$it = new GlobIterator('path/to/files/*SKU#*');
foreach ($it as $file) {
    if (!$file->isFile()) continue; //Only rename files
    $newName = str_replace('SKU#', '', $file->getPathname());
    rename($file->getPathname(), $newName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this sample:

```
$directory = 'img';
$gallery = scandir($directory);
$gallery = preg_grep ('/\.jpg$/i', $gallery);
// print_r($gallery);

foreach ($gallery as $k2 => $v2) {
    if (exif_imagetype($directory."/".$v2) == IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
        rename($directory.'/'.$v2, $directory.'/'.str_replace("#SKU","",$v2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$curDir = "/path/to/unprocessed/files";
$newdir = "/path/to/processed/files";

if ($handle = opendir($curDir)) 
{
    //make the new directory if it does not exist
    if(!is_dir($newdir))
    {
         mkdir($newdir);
    }

    //Iterate the files
    while ($file = readdir($handle))
    {
            // invalid files check (directories or files with no extentions)
            if($file != "." && $file != "..")
            {
                //copy
                copy($curDir."/".$file, $newdir."/".$file);
        
                $newName = str_replace("SKU#","",$file); 
                
                //rename
                rename($newdir."/".$file, $newdir."/".$newName.".jpg");
            
            }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```