# opencart - Url of inserted images is not encoded properly

Tags: php, opencart

When inserting an image inside the ckeditor the url output is `http://site.com/image/data/004 - Copy.jpg` instead of `http://site.com/image/data/004%20-%20Copy.jpg`

Keep in mind that images get displayed properly on the site but when I want to send an email the email client (gmail for example) encodes the url file name to `http://site.com/image/data/004+-+Copy.jpg` and that returns a 404.

I can fix this with rawurlencode() but I can't seem to find where to add it. Any ideas?
[image]

**EDIT:**
I found where to edit (filemanager.tpl)

`window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(<?php echo $fckeditor; ?>, '<?php echo $directory; ?>' + $(this).find('input[name=\'image\']').attr('value'));`

How do I encode `$(this).find('input[name=\'image\']').attr('value')` with rawurlencode?

Comment: Perhaps a quick and dirty fix would be to not upload files that has spaces in them? Or am I missing something (I don't know/use opencart)

Comment: Yes, that would be an easy fix but there's already a lot of images and this site is for a client.

Comment: Renaming images also would be the right thing to do, not just a quick fix, IMHO. Going other way sounds more like a quick fix to me. For easy batch renaming, see this post: [ bulk-rename-files-in-a-folder-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993590/bulk-rename-files-in-a-folder-php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, you can't use PHP's `rawurlencode` directly, but you can improvise by implementing your own JavaScript version of the function...

```
function rawurlencode (str) {
    return encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/!/g, '%21').replace(/'/g, '%27').replace(/\(/g, '%28').
    replace(/\)/g, '%29').replace(/\*/g, '%2A');
}
```

And...

```
rawurlencode($(this).find('input[name=\'image\']').attr('value'));
```