# Trim the text "th_" from variable and save the result to a new variable?

Tags: php

My question is quick and simple.

I am creating a gallery and I am fetching my full-size images and my thumbnails from a directory using glob.

I have a variable for the path to my thumbnail images : `images/photo-strip/thumb/*.jpg`

I am reducing the path `images/photo-strip/thumb/*.jpg` to `*.jpg` using `basename()` and I save that to `$filename`

Then I re-build the path to the full size image like this: `$pathToFull = 'images/photo-strip/' . $filename;`

My files inside the thumb folder are named like so: `th_*.jpg` and the full size images are `*.jpg` (exactly matching but without the th).

I then have an echo that puts the HTML, with thumbnail path in an `<img>` tag and fullsize path to an `<a>` tag.

Problem is the path to my full-size images is wrong because of the th_ in the filenames of the images.

**Is there a way to trim the `th_` from `$filename` and save it to something like `$full_filename` so I can correct the filename for the full-size images?**

I could easily rename the thumbnail images to exclude th_ and this would solve my problem but I would prefer to leave the file names as is.

**EDIT:**

I am using BCMCFC's method as it get's rid of two lines of code that I don't neccessarily have to have.

Thanks for the speedy answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rebuilding the path, it sounds like you could simplify the process as follows:

```
$img = str_replace('images/photo-strip/thumb/th_', 'images/photo-strip/', $originalImage);
```

Or just:

```
$img = str_replace('thumb/th_', '', $originalImage);
```

Comment: This is very nice, it allows me to skip using basename to find the filename and allows me to cut out the line that I had "rebuilding" the filepath.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function to replace "th_" by empty string

Comment: This is what I ended up using but to some further extent as shown in bcmcfc's answer.  +1 and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look no further than `$full_filename = substr($filename,3);`

Comment: Great answer and it works but I like bcmcfc's answer better.  It allows me to cut out two lines of code.  Thanks though!!

Answer (score 1):

This would be the most elegant way to do it:-

```
$filename = 'th_myimage.jpg';
$pathToFull = 'images/photo-strip/' . preg_replace('/^(th_)?/', '', $filename);
// $filename would be 'myimage.jpg'
```

This regular expression pattern would replace **only** the first occurrence of `th_` and if it was at the start of the string.

Comment: +1 for a very good answer.  I am using bcmcfc's answer as it cuts down on the amount of code needed to achieve what I want.  I would use this if it weren't for not being worried about other occurences of th_ later in the filename.  I very specific with my naming conventions so there is no need to be worried about that happening.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This has an implementation for batch renaming files in a directory.

[Bulk Rename Files in a Folder - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993590/bulk-rename-files-in-a-folder-php)

Answer (score 0):

You could use "explode" to split the string on the "_" character to an array, then get the latter element of the array.

```
$myarray = explode("_", $filename);
if(count($myarray)>1){
    $full_filename = $myarray[1];
}
```