# Bulk update in php using some conditions for filename

Tags: php

I have a folder and have multiple files over there. The file has the below pattern for example.

The file names should be renamed from

```
file1.mp4.png
file2.flv.png
file3.xxx.png (xxx - can be anything)
```

to as follows (the last extension remains).

```
file1.png
file2.png
file3.png
```

**Files having non-png extension should be left untouched.**

I am using the logic mentioned in [Bulk Rename Files in a Folder - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993590/bulk-rename-files-in-a-folder-php)

```
$handle = opendir("path to directory");

if ($handle) {
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        $newName = (how to get new filename) // I am struck here
        rename($fileName, $newName);
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

How best I can do this to do a bulk update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// Select all PNG Files
$matches = glob("*.[pP][nN][gG]");

// check if we found any results
if ( is_array ( $matches ) ) {

    // loop through all files
    foreach ( $matches as $filename) {

        // rename your files here
        $newfilename = current(explode(".", $filename)).".png";
        rename($filename, $newfilename);
        echo "$filename -> $newfilename";

    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$handle = opendir("path to directory");

if ($handle) {
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        $arr_names = explode(".", $fileName);  
        $size = sizeof($arr_names);
        $ext = $arr_names[$size-1];
        if($fileName=="." || $fileName==".."  || is_dir($fileName))
        {
           continue; // skip png  
        }

         if($ext=='png' || $ext=='PNG')
         {
             $newName = $arr_names[0].".".$ext;         

             rename($fileName, $newName);
         }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: I suggest to add test if file is "." or ".." or is a directory and skip it.

Comment: @Purus try it. it will skip you png files

Comment: I meant png files should not be skipped as in my questions.

Comment: You are welcome. Change is_dir($fileName) with is_dir("$handle/$fileName)

Comment: @Purus ok i got it i am updating answer

Comment: @Letizia `is_dir` doesn't require `handle` see http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-dir.php

Comment: Yes, I was wrong, instead of "path to directory" I said $handle.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest using **regex**

```
$handle = opendir("path to directory");

if ($handle) {
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        $newName = preg_replace("/\.(.*?)\.png$/", '', $fileName); // removes .xxx.png
        rename($fileName, ($newName . '.png')); // renames file1.png
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```