# Batch rename files in Windows 10

Tags: cmd, file-rename, windows-scripting

I have a folder in which I need to rename all of the files to replace a string with another string:

```
File 01 (Something) ABC.txt ---> File 01 - ABC.txt
File 02 (Something) DEF.txt ---> File 02 - DEF.txt
```

In other words I need to replace `(Somthing)` with `-`.

I tried the `ren` solution mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9383305/5530965) but I got `The syntax of the command is incorrect`. Here's what I tried:

```
ren *(Something)* *-*
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a `cmd` approach but it looks like my needs can't be done with the `ren` command.

So I ended up just creating a simple PHP script based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4993620/5530965):

```php
<?php
$path = 'E:/My Folder';
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($fileName = readdir($handle))) {
        if(in_array($fileName, array('.', '..'))) {
            continue;
        }
        $newName = str_replace("(Something)", "-", $fileName);
        rename("{$path}/{$fileName}", "{$path}/{$newName}");
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```